# How to package .json files for use in an ANE for iOS

Tags: ios, json, resources, adobe, ane

I am creating an Adobe Native Extension (ANE) for use with iOS. The native code in the main .a library file used for the ANE depends on 3rd party frameworks which themselves depend on the definitions of JSON objects defined in several .json files. I can package the 3rd party frameworks with the ANE just fine - it's the .json files that I'm having difficulties with.

I've tried packaging the .json files into the main .a library file, although I don't know if I did it the right way.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to package the files into the ANE rather than the library file. Try putting them in the same directory as the library (a) file when you're creating your ANE.